# Processing responses on JQuery Ajax requests to return them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

Update : I was able to use the callbacks but i really need to get the value returned by the callback. so i did this :

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        console.log(testcall());

    });


    function testcall()
    {
        return result = doXHR(xhrCallback);
    }
    // create a function the returns the result for test.json
    function doXHR(callback)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'test.json',
            success : callback,
        });
    }


    function xhrCallback(result)
    {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
```

It turns out it will still be undefined.

===========================================================================

I'm in a bit of a problem, I have a function that sends an ajax request.
I have seen the other questions regarding this topic, but it seems that the answers doesn't solve my problem.

```
function callXHR(params)
{
    var req = $.post(params.url, params.data);   

    // process for success
    req.success(function(response){

       // response processing
    });


    // this function needs to return the processed response from
    // my req.success
    return; //<the value processed on the req.success>;

}
```

I have already studied the concept of deferred objects and promises. The thing is i just don't know how to wait for the ajax call to be resolve before i return the values and end my function.

thank you very much!

cheers!!!

Comment: Have you seen [this definitive question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)?  You need to use a callback.

Comment: simply return deferred object

Comment: i was able to return the deferred object. How may I resolve it? because I still need to get the value from the response from the deferred object.